# JavaScript: Not a function

Tags: javascript, function

I've found the threads with exactly the same title I used, but I couldn't really get the connection to my problem (I'm very new to JavaScript which might be the issue).

I'm working on extending the MediaWiki VisualEditor. Part of it is to replicate a js class/script.

This is where I get the error:

```
[...]
ve.ui.TextColorSearchDialog.static.textColorSearchWidget = ve.ui.TextColorSearchWidget;

/* Methods */

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
ve.ui.TextColorSearchDialog.prototype.initialize = function () {
    ve.ui.TextColorSearchDialog.super.prototype.initialize.apply( this, arguments );
    this.searchWidget = new this.constructor.static.textColorSearchWidget( {
        $: this.$
    } ).on( 'select', this.onSearchWidgetSelect.bind( this ) );
    this.$body.append( this.searchWidget.$element );
};
[...]
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.constructor.static.textColorSearchWidget is not a function
```

(second line of the initialize function)

While this work perfectly fine (the original file):

```
[...]
ve.ui.LanguageSearchDialog.static.languageSearchWidget = ve.ui.LanguageSearchWidget;

/* Methods */

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
ve.ui.LanguageSearchDialog.prototype.initialize = function () {
    ve.ui.LanguageSearchDialog.super.prototype.initialize.apply( this, arguments );
    this.searchWidget = new this.constructor.static.languageSearchWidget( {
        $: this.$
    } ).on( 'select', this.onSearchWidgetSelect.bind( this ) );
    this.$body.append( this.searchWidget.$element );
};
[...]
```

I've also tried to assign ve.ui.LanguageSearchWidget instead of ve.ui.TextColorSearchWidget in the first line of my file to see if it's a problem with the constructor of ve.ui.TextColorSearchWidget, but I got the same error so I guess the problem has to be in the part I posted - which I do not get, as it's exactly the same with only Language replaced with TextColor? (Ofc I created the file ve.ui.TextColorSearchWidget as well).

Edit: If it's of relevance, these are the full classes:

The original LanguageSearchDialog: http://pasted.co/4a429272

My replication of the original LanguageSearchDialog, TextColorSearchDialog:
http://pasted.co/d2dbdd70

The original Widget (which is created in the working LanguageSearchDialog): http://pasted.co/89daa63b

My replication of the original Widget for my TextcolorSearchDialog: http://pasted.co/164194ce

Comment: No idea about your browser/environment but you should get an error message with information about what is not a function and a line number. Can you see that?

Comment: Hey, yea, I already edited the info into the post, just forgot it, sorry.

Comment: please do `console.log(new this.constructor.static);` right above this line.. `this.searchWidget = ...` and post it.

Comment: @Pamplam I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: this.constructor.static is not a function" when trying to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was not able to find out what causes the problem, but in this case I could fix it by simply bypassing `ve.ui.TextColorSearchDialog.static.textColorSearchWidget` and putting `ve.ui.TextColorSearchWidget` directly into the call, resulting in

`this.searchWidget = new ve.ui.TextColorSearchWidget( {
        $: this.$ [...]`

which got rid of the error.